# how to clear specific text formatting in word, programmatically using interop c#

Tags: c#, windows, office-interop, office-automation

I have created one windows application, in which we are automating MsOffice.

Currently i'm working on, "Clear All Formatting on text". This method will clear the formatting on the specific text in word, and will set default fonts and its size.

The following is the code, what I tried so far:

```
public static bool ClearAllFormatting(IQuestion question, string filename, string text )
    {
        WordInterop.Application wordApplication = GetOrCreateWordApplication(question.ObjectStore);

        try
        {
            //Avoid screen flickering or unwanted alerts while initializing
            wordApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;
            WordInterop.WdAlertLevel displayAlertLevel = wordApplication.DisplayAlerts;
            wordApplication.DisplayAlerts = WordInterop.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

            WordInterop.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(filename);
            WordInterop.Paragraph para = wordDocument.Paragraphs[1];
            WordInterop.Range range = para.Range;
            if(range.Find.Execute(text))
            {
                range.Find.ClearFormatting();

            }


            object missing = Type.Missing;

            wordDocument.Save();
            object save_changes = false;
            wordDocument.Close(ref save_changes, ref missing, ref missing);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Cleanup(question.ObjectStore, true);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But, unfortunately this method is not clearing the formate on text.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: ClearFormatting removes the formatting that is searched for. It doesn't remove any formatting from the document itself.

Comment: solution please